# Deserialize JSON to nested C# Classes

Tags: c#, json.net, inner-classes

Below is a (slightly) stripped down response I get from a REST API upon successful creation of a new "job code" entry. I need to deserialize the response into some classes, but I'm stumped.

For reference, I'm using JSON.NET in .NET 3.5 (running in a SSIS script in SQL Server 2008 R2) to attempt my deserialization.  Here's the JSON - which I obviously have no control over as it's coming from someone else's API:

```
{
   "results":{
      "jobcodes":{
         "1":{
            "_status_code":200,
            "_status_message":"Created",
            "id":444444444,
            "assigned_to_all":false,
            "billable":true,
            "active":true,
            "type":"regular",
            "name":"1234 Main Street - Jackson"
         },
         "2":{
            "_status_code":200,
            "_status_message":"Created",
            "id":1234567890,
            "assigned_to_all":false,
            "billable":true,
            "active":true,
            "type":"regular",
            "name":"4321 Some Other Street - Jackson"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In my C# code, I do have a "JobCode" class defined which only partially maps the JSON values to properties - I'm not interested in all of the data that's returned to me:

```
[JsonObject]
class JobCode
{
    [JsonProperty("_status_code")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_status_message")]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Empty constructor for JSON serialization support
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public JobCode() { }
}
```

I'm attempting to deserialize the data via this call:

```
newResource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobCode>(jsonResponse);
```

Where `jsonResponse` is the code outputted above.
When I execute the code, "newResource" always comes back as null - which is not unexpected because I know that there are actually multiple job codes in the data and this code is trying to deserialize it into a single `JobCode` object. I tried creating a new class called `JobCodes` that looks like this:

```
class JobCodes
{
    [JsonProperty("jobcodes")]
    public List<JobCode>_JobCodes { get; set; }
}
```

And then I tried calling this (`JobCodes` instead of `JobCode`):

```
newResource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobCodes>(jsonResponse);
```

But the issue persists - my return object is null.
What's throwing me off, I think, is the presence of the "1" and "2" identifiers. I don't know how to account for their presence in my object design and/or usage of the JSON.NET class / property attributes like `[JsonObject]`,`[JsonProperty]`, etc.

When I run the JSON data through [JSON2CSharp](https://json2csharp.com/), it constructs some weird-looking classes, so that hasn't proven too effective. I've validated the JSON with several different validators and it all checks out–I just don't know what I'm missing here.

Ultimately, I'd like to return a `List<JobCode>` from the JSON data, but I'm stumped on what I need to do to make that happen.

Comment: already tried `var newResource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JobCode>>(jsonResponse);//?`

Comment: Your JSON is proper, but.. I suppose `results` and `jobcodes` should be a collection. In your case it is not. In this case you should prepare another class with `1` and `2` mapped properties of `JobCode` type. Then another class that Contains `jobcodes` property of type class, that is build prevousily.

Comment: There are no arrays in the JSON so you won't be able to deserialize into a list.

Comment: Here's an edited version of what I get:

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JobCode]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object."

Comment: @pwas - The problem is that there could be many more instances than just "1" and "2" - the response may include up to 50 "jobcode" objects at once.  I'd be leery of hard-coding specific properties for "1" and "2" - unless I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Jake Bullet I'm suggesting to make it an array (in JSON) instead of properties `1` and `2`. For example: `... "jobcodes": [{ \* one job code *\ }, { \* second jobcode *\ }]` and so on...

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, that's not an option, unfortunately.  I have no control over how the JSON is provided because it is coming from a third-party API.  I can only work with the data as it's given to me...

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. In this case I suggest you to play with `JObject` from Newtonsoft. Then you could manually iterate throu JSON properties `1`, `2` and so on (via LINQ) and then deserialize single `JobCode` from each property.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

1. You don't have a class defined at the root level.  The class structure needs to match the *entire* JSON, you can't just deserialize from the middle.
2. Whenever you have an object whose keys can change, you need to use a `Dictionary<string, T>`.  A regular class won't work for that; neither will a `List<T>`.

Make your classes like this:

```
class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}

class Results
{
    [JsonProperty("jobcodes")]
    public Dictionary<string, JobCode> JobCodes { get; set; }
}

class JobCode
{
    [JsonProperty("_status_code")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("_status_message")]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize like this:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

[Working demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ivt7cO)

Answer (score 25):

For those out there that may need some more help with the JSON Class Configuration, try: https://json2csharp.com/

Or even easier, in Visual Studio, go to: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste as JSON Classes

Comment: This does not address the question that was asked _at all_, and should be deleted. The question is about deserializing JSON data into C# data, not how to generate C# classes. Furthermore, the OP mentions in their question they already use this website to generate classes.

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't change the scheme of JSON, and you can't set constant No. of properties, I'd suggest you to use `JObject`

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);

var results = jobject["results"];
var jobcodes = results["jobcodes"];

var output = jobcodes.Children<JProperty>()
                     .Select(prop => prop.Value.ToObject<JobCode>())
                     .ToList();
```

Warning: code assumes, that JSON is always in proper schema. You should also handle invalid schema (for example where property is not of `JobCode` scheme).

Answer (score 0):

You can also deserialize your json to an object of your target class, and then read its properties as per normal:

```
var obj = DeSerializeFromStrToObj<ClassToSerialize>(jsonStr);
Console.WriteLine($"Property: {obj.Property}");
```

where `DeSerializeFromStrToObj` is a custom class that makes use of reflection to instantiate an object of a targeted class:

```
    public static T DeSerializeFromStrToObj<T>(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            var o = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            try
            {
                var jsonDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                var props = o.GetType().GetProperties();

                if (props == null || props.Length == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error: properties from target class '{typeof(T)}' could not be read using reflection");
                    return default;
                }

                if (jsonDict.Count != props.Length)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error: number of json lines ({jsonDict.Count}) should be the same as number of properties ({props.Length})of our class '{typeof(T)}'");
                    return default;
                }

                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    if (prop == null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Error: there was a prop='null' in our target class '{typeof(T)}'");
                        return default;
                    }

                    if (!jsonDict.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Error: jsonStr does not refer to target class '{typeof(T)}'");
                        return default;
                    }

                    var value = jsonDict[prop.Name];
                    Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                    object safeValue = value ?? Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
                    prop.SetValue(o, safeValue, null); // initialize property
                }
                return o;
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e2.Message);
                return o;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return default;
        }
    }
```

A complete working example class can be found in my enhanced answer to a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70463398/7586301)