# Reading JSON with a property name that changes

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to ready a JSON file with contents similar to this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "1357": {
      "icon": "smiley-face",
      "name": "happy"
    },
    "success": true
  }
}
```

This example below works but the problem I'm having is that the property name for `classid` is always different.  How can I deserialize the `classid` without knowing the property name?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class ClassId
{
    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("1357")] // this key is always different
    public ClassId classid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(container.Result.classid.Icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is that `ClassId`?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when the keys in the JSON can change, you can handle it by using a `Dictionary<string, T>` in place of a regular class.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25052293/10263) for an example of what I mean.  However, this approach will not work in your case because you also have a boolean `success` flag as part of your result, and that will not mix with a `Dictionary<string, ClassId>`.  So, instead, you will need to use a `JsonConverter` to deserialize your `Result` class.  Here is the code you will need:

```
class ResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Result);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        Result result = new Result();
        result.Success = (bool)obj["success"];
        JProperty prop = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name != "success");
        if (prop != null)
        {
            result.classid = prop.Value.ToObject<ClassId>(serializer);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `Result` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResultConverter))]
public class Result
{
    ...
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ACR5Un

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject; you might need to create a [JsonReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) to implement this logic.