# c# - Deserialize dynamic property name to c# class

Tags: json.net

Json can be any of following and i would not know the master list how do i covert to c# class

```
{"title": {"fr-FR": "L'Auberge Espagnole"}}
{"title": {"en-GB": "Van Wilder 2: The Rise of Taj"}} 
{"title": {"fr-CA": "Crooklyn"}} 
{"title": {"es-ES": "Julieta"} }
{"title":{"en":"In Ice Cold Blood"}}
{"title":{"fr":"spiderman"}}
{"title":{"es":"robot"}}

I tried below and it did not work

public class RootObject
{
    public Title title { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public Dictionary<object, string> items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This probably has an answer already.  Try something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON to C# Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes)

Comment: It should be `public class RootObject { public Dictionary<string, string> title { get; set; } }`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked with