# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject cannot deserialize valid JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I am perplexed as why the `DeserializeObject` method cannot deserialize valid JSON:

```
string source = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Source);
Maintenance ticket_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Maintenance>(source); //breaks here
```

When I hit my endpoint, I receive the following:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: {. Path 'elements', line 21, position 5."

I see where that is happening. `Elements` has many different attributes, `Elements` is an array.

In the `Maintenance` class I have:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Elements { get; set; }
```

I used the JSONLint website to make sure `source` was valid JSON, and it is.

[Maintenance Class](https://gist.github.com/ornerymoose/e8db1f52918d9fa2dc528491499ae17f)

Some of the JSON output:

```
{
  "doc_type": "ticket",
  "updated_date": 12345,
  "ticket_number": "1234",
  "start": 1234,
  "summary": "hello",
  "description": "do stuff",
  "active": true,
  "related_tickets": [],
  "tags": [],
  "elements": [
    {
      "last_updated": 5678,
      "entry_id": null,
      "name": "something",
```

Any insight as to why I cannot deserialize this JSON would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON and the class definition just from this it is difficult to say something.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: That is totally valid JSON but does not conform to the schema of the Maintenance class. The items in "elements" are not strings. They are some other complex object. Create another object to represent that thing and use it in definition of elements, `IEnumerable<Element>`. You could also use object if you didn't really care about getting at its properties.

Comment: change the type of Elements to IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>

Comment: Whenever you have valid JSON, DO NOT try to hand-craft the classes to deserialize into. Use http://json2csharp.com, it will produce the correct class definitions.

Comment: @mikez elements in the sql server database are in a varchar column like so: `element1;element2;element3`. When I'm creating my `elasticMaintenance` data I create Elements: `Elements = d.Element_Ids.Split(';'),`

Comment: @DnfD What is the value for "elements" in the json you posted then? It's obviously not a string that was split by ';'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to de-serializing a list of ***objects***: `elements[{}]` to a list of ***string*** elements: `public IEnumerable<string> Elements`

What you can do is create a wrapper `Elements` class with properties that match the JSON payload like this

```
 public class Elements {
  public DateTime last_updated {get;set;}
  public int? entry_id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
 }
```

then in your `Maintenance.cs` you can change the `Elements` property to

```
public IEnumerable<Elements> Elements { get; set; }
```

Also take note of the data type in the JSON payload. Some are not strings. for example is `last_updated`

Comment: This looks like a great approach. Will try first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your elements is not an array of stings like you defined in the object. From what it looks from the JSON snippet you have objects inside the elements array.

```
"elements": [{
      "last_updated": 5678,
      "entry_id": null,
      "name": "something",
}
```

This defines an object with properties last_updated, entry_id, name so this should map to a class or a Dictionary like somebody already suggested in the comments.

Else it should look something like this in JSON:

```
"elements": ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use List or IEnumerable of string insted Maintenance like this code:

```
var ticket_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(source);
```

then set your element of Maintenance class
 like this code

```
    Elements =ticket_data ;
```

Comment: But I need the deserialization to be based on the `Maintenance` class

Comment: You can deserialize to a class. I have many instances of similar code throughout the codebase that are working fine.

Comment: this link solve your problem :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes