# json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, converters

The response to my web request coming as the following (not under my control):

```
{
"nasdaq_imbalance": 
{
    "name": "nasdaq_imbalance", 
    "group": "Market Data", 
    "description": null
},
"DXOpen IM": 
{
    "name": "DXOpen IM", 
    "group": "Daily",
    "description": null
}, 
"Float Shares": 
{
    "name": "Float Shares", 
    "group": "Daily", 
    "description": null
},
```

}

Somehow, I need to deserialize that into C# object that contains a list of objects...
Basically I need a list of objects like that:

```
public class Dataset    {
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string group { get; set; } 
    public string description { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: You can go to http://quicktype.io and paste your json in there, it will generate the classes, and the deser code, and even comments to tell you how to use it

Comment: @CaiusJard that probably isn't the best duplicate to use, considering JavaScriptSerializer is deprecated.

Comment: That's the trouble with C# JSON Qs.. too many duplicates.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052293/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-classes

Comment: @CaiusJard The issue is with SO. It's easier for me to type a short answer like that than to try find a duplicate and hope a moderator actually looks at it when I flag it.

Comment: A better duplicate is [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/3744182).  The answers there say to 1) Use a dictionary if the root object property names are not fixed; 2) If the root object property names are fixed, use a root object with properties marked with `JsonPropertyAttribute` attributes, e.g. `[JsonProperty("DXOpen IM")] public Dataset     DXOpenIM { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Json.NET, you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dataset>>(json)` and the keys of the dictionary will be `nasdaq_imbalance`, `DXOpen IM`, `Float Shares`

Comment: I will try shortly, so far it is the most promising solution posted here...BTW, I was searching here A to Z and could not find similar structure since it is kinda pseudo-jason

Comment: Great thinking Charlieface! From the Dictionary I can easily make the list...