# How to deserialize json with incorrect repetitive structure

Tags: c#, graphql, json.net

Getting results back from Shopify's graphql which it not in a standard structure to be able to deserialize simply.

Here's the result, but note the list of `item1`, `item2`, etc which can be from 1 to 100 items returned and this is the part I'm not sure how to deserialize and is my main question. Specifically, to a strongly typed `List<Item>` collection of items such that I can they query for any `UserErrors`, i.e. something like: `lstItems.Any(l => l.UserErrors.Any())`.

The second issue is that `data` will not always have these contents...other GraphQL queries will have different responses. Perhaps in this case, I should rename `data` in the string to another class name that will have these contents, then deserialize?

```
{
    "data":{
        "item1":{
            "userErrors":[
                
            ]
        },
        "item2":{
            "userErrors":[
                
            ]
        }
    },
    "extensions":{
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's what QuickType comes up with, but again, it assumes a discrete list of `Items`:

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class InventoryUpdateResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("extensions")]
        public Extensions Extensions { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("item1")]
        public Item Item1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("item2")]
        public Item Item2 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("userErrors")]
        public UserError[] UserErrors { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UserError
    {
        [JsonProperty("field")]
        public string[] Field { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Extensions
    {
        ....
    }
        
}
```

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, Item> Data` should do the trick. The keys become `Item1,Item2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp)

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, Item> Data` is strongly typed.  You could just do `Data.Values.Any(l => l.UserErrors.Any())`.

Comment: @dbc you're right...brain fart on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charlieface for pointing me in the right direction. Here's what I ultimately did. The other part I was trying to figure out, which I didn't know and articulate at the time of writing the question, was how to separate out the `data` portion of the response, which had this issue from the `extensions` portion, which is structured properly and can be simply deserialized to a class.

- So to split out the `data` portion, you parse the string to a `JObject`
- Then deserialize just that portion to the `Dictionary` as suggested
- Then you can iterate through the `Dictionary` to get all the standard class objects and do as you with with them (add them to their own list, etc.)

code:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response);
Dictionary<string, InventoryUpdateResult> dicRawResults;
var data = (JObject)jsonObject["data"];
if (data != null)
{
    dicRawResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, InventoryUpdateResult>>(data.ToString());
    foreach(var result in dicRawResults)
    {
        InventoryUpdateResult inventoryUpdateResult = result.Value;
    }
}
```

Then I extracted the `extensions` portion and converted that to the class object as such:

```
jsonObject = JObject.Parse(shopifyResponse.Value);
var jExtension = (JObject)jsonObject["extensions"];
if (jExtension != null)
{
    queryCost = jExtension.ToObject<GraphExtensions>();
    .....
}
```