# Multiple employees Json gives Deserializing error

Tags: c#, json.net, webapi

I am reading 2 REST APIs using Httpclient in C#. The APIs return following employee data in JSON format:

**1st API**

```
{
    "status": "OK", 
    "content": {
        "empid1": 89900,
        "empid2": 45550,
        "empid3": 22350}
}
```

**2nd API**

```
 {
    "status": "OK", 
     "content": {
              "empid1": "grade1",
              "empid1": "grade2",
              "empid1": "grade2"}}
```

Classes defined and code used is as follows:

```
 public class content
    {
        public string empid { get; set; } // e.g. empid3
        public double salary { get; set; } // e.g. 89900
        public string grade { get; set; } // e.g. Grade1
    }
    public sealed class WrapperEmployees
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<content> empdata { get; set; } = new List<data>();
    }
```

To deserialize, used this-

```
WrapperEmployees nj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WrapperEmployees>(response);
```

But, last line gives error on deserialization:

> Cannot deserialize current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CsharpSample.App_Code.Employee]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.    Path 'content.emp1', line 4, position 18.

Is my class structure incorrect?
My ultimate aim is to fetch common data from both APIs against employees.

Comment: you have duplicate keys `"empid1"`. although JSON _technically_ does not forbid this, you definitely should _not_ do stuff like this unless you _absolutely_ have to. talk to whoever's responsible for this API and make them fix their code to be less awful.

Comment: Unrelated : `public double salary { get; set; } // e.g. 89900` - do not use floating point for monetary amounts.

Comment: And the json property is named "content", not "data".

Comment: `into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[CsharpSample.App_Code.Employee]'` hints to that you are not posting the code that creates the exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse unreadable json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253204/how-to-parse-unreadable-json)

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: @Fildor , Have corrected content to data, issue persists

Comment: Try `public Dictionary<string, object> empdata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();` then map it into the object yourself, based on whether the value is a `string` or an `int`

Comment: @Charlieface , Thanks, your solution worked. Please put it as answer, so I can Mark it 'Accepted'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, @Charlieface .

Comment: @Fildor Please vote for a suitable dupe

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use specific classes for each json deserialization:

```
class EmployeesSalaries {
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, int> content { get; set; };
}
class EmployeesGrades {
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> content { get; set; };
}
```

Option 2: deserialize to common class, but you will get 'good' `content` values only if they are int/string. If they will be objects - you will have JObjects as values.

```
class EmployeesData {
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, object> content { get; set; };
}
```