# Getting JSON data into C# strings

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I'm making an app and I need to extract data from JSON files dynamically.

Here is a snippet of the JSON file:

```
{
    "004bb5ee-34ba-484a-924b-31412d898e7e": {
        "title": "obj_survivalobject_elevatordoor_left"
    },
    "00284190-1484-4286-a198-b2ddef768c2e": {
        "description": "Adds shock absorption and provides stability. Great for vehicles to prevent them from easily flipping over. This suspension has a lot of bounce, making it ideal for off-road vehicles.",
        "title": "Off-Road Suspension 2"
    },
    "011c1ffd-7146-4e8d-8c18-17247d768ae2": {
        "title": "obj_spaceship_wall04"
    }
}
```

There is lots more in the file.
But I only need to get the title and the parent of that title. Eg:

```
Tag: "00284190-1484-4286-a198-b2ddef768c2e"
Name: "Off-Road Suspension 2"
```

I don't want the description and not all have one.

I will also be using JSON files that are selected by the user while the application is running.

Comment: Have you ever deserialized json before? Is there any reason why you haven't tried to deserialise this to a `Dictionary<string,CustomClass>` and pick the results from that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Description>>(json); 
var list = jsonDeserialized.Select(kvp => new TagName { Tag = kvp.Key, 
Name=kvp.Value.title} ).ToList();

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

output

```
[{"Tag":"004bb5ee-34ba-484a-924b-31412d898e7e","Name":"obj_survivalobject_elevatordoor_left"},
{"Tag":"00284190-1484-4286-a198-b2ddef768c2e","Name":"Off-Road Suspension 2"},
{"Tag":"011c1ffd-7146-4e8d-8c18-17247d768ae2","Name":"obj_spaceship_wall04"}]
```

or this way

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine ( $"Tag : {item.Tag}, Name: {item.Name}");
        
}
```

classes

```
public class Description
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class TagName
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deserializing your Json file into a collection (list/dict/etc).

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) for details about Serializing and Deserializing in C#.