# Json deserialize object array with dynamic property names

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamic, system.text.json

I want to deserialize a json object in c# using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` of System.Text.Json.
The json looks like this:

```json
{
   "id":10,
   "authorization_ids":[
      
   ],
   "karma_user_ids":[
      2
   ],
   "group_ids":{
      "2":[
         "full"
      ],
      "4":[
         "read"
      ],
      "5":[
         "overview"
      ],
      "7":[
         "change",
         "overview"
      ],
      "10":[
         "create"
      ]
   }
}
```

But the property `group_ids` contains objects with dynamic property names that actually correspond to the ID of a group.

```
{
  2  : {full}
  4  : {read}
  5  : {overview}
  7  : {change, overview}
  10 : {create}
}
```

Now I want to deserialize group_ids to an object like this:

```
public class GroupPermission
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }

    public GroupPermission() { }
}

[Flags]
public enum Permission
{
    full = 1,
    read = 2,
    overview = 4,
    change = 8,
    create = 16
}
```

Is this possible? Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: Can you please add full JSON with `group_ids` JSON data? Not clear its behavior

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi Tanks, but what do you mean? The json of group_ids is the second json code block above. But I added a comment to make it more clear.

Comment: Neither block 1 nor block 2 is valid JSON. Please show your *actual* JSON

Comment: @Charlieface right... Sorry. Updated the thread and added the json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys) In this case, `group_ids` should be deserialized to `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` and the dictionary keys are the IDs

Comment: @B4DschK4Pp Do I understand correctly that you want to deserialize the `group_ids` to a collection of `GroupPermission`?

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```cs
    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id {get;set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("authorization_ids")]
        public List<int> AuthorizationIds {get;set;}
        
        [JsonPropertyName("karma_user_ids")]
        public List<int> KarmaUserIds {get;set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("group_ids")]
        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> GroupIds {get;set;}

        public RootObject()
        {
            AuthorizationIds = new List<int>();
            KarmaUserIds = new List<int>();
            GroupIds = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        }
    }
```

To test it:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText("./file.json");
    var objs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
}
```