# querying dynamic json using c#

Tags: c#, json.net

We have the following Json

```
{
  "@message": "some message",
  "outputs": {
    "outone": {
      "value": "eastus2"
    },
    "outtwo": {
      "value": "r7ty-network"
    }
  }
}
```

the outputs section contain 2 objects "outone" and "outtwo", we are struggling to get hold of the the names "outone" and "outtwo" and its corresponding value property.

we generated c# classes and everything was working as expected, but later we were told that the  values "outone" and "outtwo",are dynamic, they can be named anything.

any pointers will help.

Thanks -Nen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys) Use `Dictionary<string, ValueObject> outputs` and create a class `class ValueObject { public string value; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this code using Newtonsoft.Json

```
var jsonDeserialized= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

and classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("@message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("outputs")]
    public Dictionary<string,Out> Outputs { get; set; }
}

public partial class Out
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have some kind of key value list. Here's a demo in form of a test that's green:

**UPDATE: Took care of eventual duplicate "keys"**

```
[TestMethod]
public void JObject_Test()
{
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(
        @"{
            ""@message"": ""some message"",
            ""outputs"": {
              ""outone"": {
                ""value"": ""eastus2""
              },
              ""outtwo"": {
                ""value"": ""r7ty-network""
              }
            }
        }");

    var outputs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    foreach (var jproperty in jObject["outputs"].Children<JProperty>())
    {
        outputs.Add(
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(jproperty.Name,
                (string)((JObject)jproperty.Value)["value"]));
    }

    Assert.AreEqual("outone", outputs[0].Key);
    Assert.AreEqual("eastus2", outputs[0].Value);

    Assert.AreEqual("outtwo", outputs[1].Key);
    Assert.AreEqual("r7ty-network", outputs[1].Value);
}
```