# How can I read a simple JSON file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "0101": 1,
    "0102": 2,
    "0201": 3,
    "0202": 4,
    "0301": 5,
    "0302": 6,
    "0401": 7,
    "0402": 8
}
```

At some point in my code, I will be building the key, and I want to get the value for that key. So for example I will build `0101` and I want to get the 1 from the configuration above. This is what I have (that doesn't work):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file_config.json"))
{
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    object config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    //string fullKey = process to construct the key...
    var ID = config[fullKey]
}
```

I can't do `config[fullKey]` to get my value. What would be the best way to go on reading these values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `System.Text.Json` you can accomplish what you're looking for with the following:

```
var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
var ID = config[fullKey];
```

Using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
```