# How to setup json deserizlization from Object to Array in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialization

I got this strange API response from external service:

```
{
    "Columns": {
      "1": {
        "Fuels": [
          "1",
          "10",
          "4",
          "4"
        ]
      },
...
      "6": {
        "Fuels": [
          "1",
          "4",
          "10"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

By default, all converters (json -> to csharp model) does models like this:

```
public class _1
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class _2
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class _3
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class _4
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class Columns
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
    public _2 _2 { get; set; }
    public _3 _3 { get; set; }
    public _4 _4 { get; set; }
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
public class Column
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}
```

I think it's a side developers fault with `Json` serialization, because `Columns` should be an `Array`, but it's an Objects :(

I need to somehow convert this to Array, maybe it is some `Newtonsoft` or default .NET Json converter `attributes` or something to do that without writing custom deserializer?
I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: `JObject.Parse(json)["Columns"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, Model>>().Values`?

Comment: @PeterCsala is it possible to do by model attributes, to do not write some additional code for parsing?

Comment: If you define your `Columns` property as `Dictionary<int, Model>` then it will work with the default json converter. Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SpK84a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you, idea with `Dictionary` helps, post answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Json.Net can deserialize any object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm) into a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

You can specialise the key's and value's types, in your case:

- int
- Column

Where `Column` is defined as

```
public class Column
{
   public List<string> Fuels {get; set;}
}
```

---

So, if you define your `Columns` property in your root class as `Dictionary<int, Column>` then it will work fine with the default json converter

```
public class Root
{
   public Dictionary<int, Column> Columns;
}
```

Imperative usage:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json).Columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Column> columns = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["Columns"]).Properties()
                    .Select(v => new Column(v.Name, v.Value["Fuels"].ToObject<List<string>>()))
                    .ToList();
```

class

```
public class Column
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    private List<string> Fuels { get; set; }

    public Column(string number, List<string> fuels)

    {
        Number = number;
        Fuels = fuels;
    }
    public Column(){}
}
```

Comment: +rep, thanks much, but the way with `Dictionary` is better

Comment: @hamaronooo why then you ask to make fuels private?

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because the OP is looking for an attribute based solution. Linq 2 json is not that.

Comment: What about OP is looking  private List<string> Fuels?  Do you think that OP really understand what he needs and what is better? I newer down vote any answers if they are working properly, doesn't  matter what I am thinking that OP is thinking.  It is always good to have an alternative solution. A list could fit better for somebody else who understands that  a typed object is always better.

Comment: @PeterCsala  I explained you already. Because your solution is wrong. It will not  deserialize private List<string> Fuels. Otherwise your solution is just a duplicate, since here 99 % Json answers are offering a Dictionary. I would be ashamed to offer this.

Comment: What private are you talking about?

Comment: @PeterCsala Look at OP column class

Comment: @Serge I'm Sorry! It's my fault, typo... of course it's public :(

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your reasoning. You have downvoted my, because the OP's code is not working.

Comment: @PeterCsala I downvoted because your solution was not working with OP model but mine was working. But if you had not downvoted mine, I would never touch yours. As I told I never downvoting anybodys answer, since I understand that the person was trying his best. I only downvote in one case - when somebody copies my answer and posts it as it is his.

Answer (score -3):

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class _1
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class _6
{
    public List<string> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class Columns
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
    public _6 _6 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Columns Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you readed OP's question?