# List keys inside a child for JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file with the following data:

```
{ 
  "users": {
    "xyz ": {
      "Name": "abc ",
    },
    "x ": {
      "Name": "xy ",
    },
    "abc": {
      "Name": "ijk",
    },
  }
}
```

I deserialize the JSON file in C# to a dynamic data type by following code:

```cs
dynamic keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Now I wanna retrieve the name of keys present inside the child of **users**.

I want the following output:

```
xyz
x
abc
```

How can I list the name of the keys?

Comment: Do you particularly *need* to use dynamic typing here? I'd either parse it as a JObject, or use a class representation with a `Root` class containing a `Dictionary<string, User>` (where `User` has a `Name` property).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 4):

1. Read JSON as `JObject`.
2. Get `users` `JObject` from *1*.
3. Convert `JObject` to `Dictionary<string, object>` and get `Keys` from the dictionary.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));
JObject users = (JObject)obj["users"];
List<string> keys = users.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    .Keys
    .ToList();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQ36lX)

Note that the keys contain space in your attached JSON.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to deserialize  to dictionary, to parse is enough

```
List<string> keys= ((JObject) JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path))["users"])
.Properties().Select(u =>  u.Name).ToList();
```