# JSON C# deserialization

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am having trouble with deserializing data from a JSON string:

```
[{
    "Example A": [{
            "Parameter1": "Example A",
            "Parameter2": "aaa",
            "Parameter3": "2022-06-30 21:15:00.0000000",
            "Value": 11.11
        }
    ],
    "Example B": [{
            "Parameter1": "Example B",
            "Parameter2": "ccc",
            "Parameter3": "2022-06-30 21:15:00.0000000",
            "Value": 33.33
        }
    ],
    "Example C": [
        {
            "Parameter1": "Example C",
            "Parameter2": "eee",
            "TimestampUTC": "2022-06-30 21:15:00.0000000",
            "Value": null
        },
        {
            "Parameter1": "Example C",
            "Parameter2": "fff",
            "Parameter3": "2022-06-30 21:15:00.0000000",
            "Value": 44.44
        }
    ]
}]
```

What I have tried is:

```
public class ExampleA
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter3 { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleB
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter3 { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleC
{
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter3 { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class Examples
{
    [JsonProperty("Example A")]
    public List<ExampleA> ExampleA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Example B")]
    public List<ExampleB> ExampleB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Example C")]
    public List<ExampleC> ExampleC { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to test it with this:

```
Examples someVar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Examples>(JsonString);
Console.WriteLine(SomeVar.ExampleA.Count);
```

I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MyProject.Examples' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List`<T>` that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Apparently I have trouble understanding how deserialization works - what I want to do with this is something like this:

```
foreach item in Example
    // do something
    foreach thing in item
        // do something more
```

I realise I have some trouble with grasping the JSON format in this case.

I'm using .NET Core.

Comment: Square brackets in JSON is array. You must use some collection in C# for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: You should deserialize this to `List<Dictionary<string, List<Example>>>` and just have a single `Example` class

Comment: @Charlieface Are you sure that the real json classes Example,A,B,C are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an array in your json Try this

```
List<Examples> someVar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Examples>>(JsonString);
```