# Deserialize nested JSON with unique key, C#

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, deserialization

I'm working with an API that returns a JSON that has a key which is "unique". As you can see there is ***PRODUCT_1***, ***PRODUCT_2***, ***PRODUCT_3*** and the list would go on.

```
{
"success": true,
"lastUpdated": 1657211399332,
"products": {
    "PRODUCT_1": {
        "product_id": "PRODUCT_1",
        "sell_summary": [],
        "buy_summary": [],
        "quick_status": {}
    },
    "PRODUCT_2": {
        "product_id": "PRODUCT_2",
        "sell_summary": [],
        "buy_summary": [],
        "quick_status": {}
    },
    "PRODUCT_3": {
        "product_id": "PRODUCT_3",
        "sell_summary": [],
        "buy_summary": [],
        "quick_status": {}
    }
}
```

I'm using the **Newtonsoft.Json** package but I can't figure out how to make it work.

---

### **EDIT:**

With [StriplingWarrior's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) comment (*"Most likely you want to make the products property a Dictionary<string, Product>."*) I could fix my code.

I replaced `public Products[] products { get; set; }` with `public Dictionary<string, Product> products { get; set; }` and it works fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Most likely you want to make the `products` property a `Dictionary<string, Product>`.

Comment: Can you posted the json you want?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var productsObj = (JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["products"];

List<Product> products = productsObj.Properties()
    .Select(o => o.Value.ToObject<Product>())
    .ToList();

public partial class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sell_summary")]
    public List<object> SellSummary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("buy_summary")]
    public List<object> BuySummary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quick_status")]
    public object QuickStatus { get; set; }
}
```