# What C# data type would you de-serialize this Json into

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

What kind of C# data type / List / Class would I de-serialise the following json into when the 3-character codes (ara, ces, cym, dei etc) are dynamic.

Thanks!

```
"translations":{
"ara":{"official":"Ù…Ù…Ù„ÙƒØ© Ù‡ÙˆÙ„Ù†Ø¯Ø§","common":"Ù‡ÙˆÙ„Ù†Ø¯Ø§"},
"ces":{"official":"NizozemskÃ© krÃ¡lovstvÃ­","common":"Nizozemsko"},
"cym":{"official":"Kingdom of the Netherlands","common":"Netherlands"},
"deu":{"official":"Niederlande","common":"Niederlande"},
"est":{"official":"Madalmaade Kuningriik","common":"Holland"}
}"
```

When I say dynamic - at run time you don't know what they are or how many you will be returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialise this json into

a class which has a property `T(t)ranslations`

and this property is a `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
Dictionary<string,Country> translations=   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json).translations;

CountryName ara = translations["ara"];

//or

string officialDeu = translations["deu"].official; // Niederlande

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string,CountryName> translations { get; set; }
}

public class CountryName
{
    public string official { get; set; }
    public string common { get; set; }
}
```