# How to deserialize a array with indexes that contains arrays in Newtonsoft.Json in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have an API that returns a JSON of this structure:

```json
{
   "1":[
      {
         "name":"One"
      },
      {
         "name":"Two"
      }
   ],
   "2":[
      {
         "name":"Three"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to deserialize it in C# using Newtonsoft.Json. I have tried deserializing in a
`List<List<Response>>` but it didn't work.

I understand that the JSON is not necessarily good, but I can't change it since it's on a third party server.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the indexes contiguous? Do they always start at `"1"`? As a first step, you could deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, List<Result>>` and then sort the key-value pairs by key and finally select only the value

Comment: That's a dictionary, not an array. Those are keys, not indexes. You'll have to use a `Dictionary<string,...>` to deserialize this document before you can change that dictionary into a list

Comment: Yep, dictionary did it. Thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialize into a dictionary (or SortedDictionary, if the order of the elements in the dictionary matter), then take the dictionary's *Values* collection and run...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).