# Deserialize a JSON string received from an online API

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-6.0, json-deserialization

I have a JSON feed which I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Status:http://jdlf.com.au/ns/business/api",
            "countedAbsence": false,
            "description": "",
            "name": "Not Marked",
            "schoolSystemExportIdentifier": "0",
            "shortCode": "-",
            "shortName": "Not Marked",
            "statusId": "802b325b-8ab6-4c84-b782-3e376024d4a7"
        },
        {
            "__type": "Status:http://jdlf.com.au/ns/business/api",
            "countedAbsence": false,
            "description": "Student is considered to be attending(DoE 'Present In Class' Status)",
            "name": "Present",
            "schoolSystemExportIdentifier": "100",
            "shortCode": "P",
            "shortName": "Present",
            "statusId": "00205dad-44c6-405e-9958-451a7d0b5194"
        }
    ]
}
```

After deserializing the received string stream, I just want to output the name element in a simple for loop.

I have no idea what I doing wrong as `dtoDirectiries` is always returning null.

I have tried changing

```cs
var dtoDirectiries = SerializerHelper.Deserialize<List<Statuses>>(output);
```

to

```cs
List<Statuses> dtoDirectiries = SerializerHelper.Deserialize<List<Statuses>>(output);
```

with no change.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Michael

```cs
using CompassAPI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "{Removed for security}");
request.Headers.Add("CompassApiKey", "{removed for security}");
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "{removed for security}");
var content = new StringContent("{\"schoolSystemType\": \"aus\"}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(output);

var dtoDirectiries = SerializerHelper.Deserialize<List<Statuses>>(output);

for (int i = 0; i < dtoDirectiries.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dtoDirectiries[i].name);
}

Console.ReadLine();


public class Statuses
{
    [JsonProperty("__type")]
    public string __type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countedAbsence")]
    public string countedAbsence { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("schoolSystemExportIdentifier")]
    public string schoolSystemExportIdentifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shortCode")]
    public string shortCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shortName")]
    public string shortName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statusId")]
    public string statusId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `List<Statuses>` is json's `d` property of a root object. So json itself is a single object, but you are trying to interpret it as a collection.

Comment: I think its the d that causing the issue. use list with out a key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json deserialization to C# with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: No sorry it does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your JSON response is an object. You need to extract the data from `d` property.

Either working with *Newtonsoft.Json.Linq* to extract the data in`d` property:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var dtoDirectiries = JObject.Parse(output)
    .SelectToken("d")
    .ToObject<List<Statuses>>();
```

Or create a `Root` class and deserialize as `Root` instance:

```cs
var dtoDirectiries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(output)
    .Data;

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public List<Statuses> Data { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOhpPK)

Comment: Thank you.  These worked perfecttly.  I used this: 
var dtoDirectiries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(output)
    .Data;

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public List<Statuses> Data { get; set; }    
}