# Nested Json Parsing to c#(Console Application)

Tags: c#, json, parsing, datatable

I need to parse Json into C# (Console Application) and also need to view the parsed data in a datatable.

I have tried to generate the classes as far as I know.

Code:

```
   {
   "RLC": [
     {
       "PAR": ""
     },
     {
       "PAR": ""
     },
     {
       "PAR": ""
     }
   ],
   "PR":
```

Please help out.

Comment: OK. What issue are you facing here? What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: I recommend using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46825163/3181933) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25063207/3181933).

Comment: I also require to get these in datatable so how to add?@Llama

Comment: I don't understand how the data you have could be represented in a table anyway. There are ways to deserialize JSON to a DataTable but you have array properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below c# class to serialize the json

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class RecordLocator
    {
        public string PNR { get; set; }
    }

    public class PNRAmount
    {
        public string BalanceDue { get; set; }
        public string AuthorizedBalanceDue { get; set; }
        public string SegmentCount { get; set; }
        public string PassiveSegmentCount { get; set; }
        public string TotalCost { get; set; }
        public string PointsBalanceDue { get; set; }
        public string TotalPointCost { get; set; }
        public List<object> AlternateCurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public string AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<RecordLocator> RecordLocator { get; set; }
        public PNRAmount PNRAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I also require to get these in datatable so how to add?@GowriPranithBayyana